# What should be the mode and channel while restarting unit files

Tags: go, restart, systemd

In [go-systemd](https://github.com/coreos/go-systemd), what should be the second and third parameters for restarting the units.

```
// RestartUnit restarts a service.  If a service is restarted that isn't
// running it will be started.
func (c *Conn) RestartUnit(name string, mode string, ch chan<- string)    (int, error) {
return c.startJob(ch, "org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager.RestartUnit", name, mode)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [PR 203](https://github.com/coreos/go-systemd/pull/203/files), you can see [that method used/tested](https://github.com/endocode/go-systemd/blob/86fc89891ea3d7006495462e85985585ccd307eb/dbus/methods_test.go#L149-L186) as:

```
// Restart the unit
reschan = make(chan string)
_, err = conn.RestartUnit(target, "replace", reschan)
if err != nil {
    t.Fatal(err)
}

job = <-reschan
if job != "done" {
    t.Fatal("Job is not done:", job)
}
```

So you have to create your own label and channel.

From [`dbus/methods.go`](https://github.com/coreos/go-systemd/blob/2f344660b11f7285b0af86195c4456e92970f640/dbus/methods.go#L65-L75)

```
// Takes the unit to activate, plus a **mode string**.
```

> The mode needs to be one of:
>
> - **replace** (the call will start the unit and its dependencies, possibly replacing already queued jobs that conflict with this),
> - **fail** (the call will start the unit and its dependencies, but will fail if this would change an already queued job),
> - **isolate** (the call will start the unit in question and terminate all units that aren't dependencies of it),
> - **ignore-dependencies** (it will start a unit but ignore all its dependencies),
> - **ignore-requirements** (it will start a unit but only ignore the requirement dependencies).
>
> It is not recommended to make use of the latter two options.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Apart from "replace" what other starings can be used. Is there any doc whoch explains these mode.

Comment: @ambikanair Yes: I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: PR author and library maintainer here. I'll happily take a patch to clarify the documentation if you care to submit it.

Comment: @kaeso were you suggesting that to the OP? Because I found the existing documentation (https://godoc.org/github.com/coreos/go-systemd/dbus#Conn.StartUnit) clear enough myself.